# Use an array variable (index) in an Json call

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I know I'm missing something really simple here but I've been searching for a while now and haven't had any luck with a solution.

I have some json data that looks like this

```
post[{
//various post data
categories": {

    "Rants": {
        "name": "Rants",
        "slug": "rants",
        "description": "",
        "post_count": 9
}]
```

I'm trying to return the category slug using a `each()` loop

```
$.each(response.posts[0].categories, function (index) {
                alert(response.posts[0].categories.index.slug);
});
```

It works when I call `alert(response.posts[0].categories.rants.slug);` but not when i try to use the index as the key.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Take time to ensure *valid* code is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this:

```
alert(response.posts[0].categories.index.slug);
```

You are trying to read a property of `categories` called `"index"`, which doesn't exist. If you really want to read every element, you have to write the following:

```
alert(response.posts[0].categories[index].slug);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(response.posts[0].categories, function(name, category) {
    alert(category.slug);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
 alert(response.posts[0].categories[index].slug);
```

More detail

jQuery takes care of this for you. The first argument to your `.each()` callback function is the index of the current iteration of the loop. The second being the current matched DOM element  So:

```
$('#list option').each(function(index, element){
  alert("Iteration: " + index)
});
```

### Edit 1

Here is the `each` api link

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @BandonRandon you are welcome. Don't forgot to mark if it helped your.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for jQuery here. It looks like it is only getting in your way. Simply do:

```
alert(response.posts[0].categories.Rants.slug);
```

Or to loop over all of the "rants" (`category` in `categories`):

```
for (var category in response.posts[0].categories) {
  alert(response.posts[0].categories[category].slug)
}
```

Comment: yes but the data is dynamic so I don't know what `Rants` is beforehand.